# azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_data_lake_storage_gen2 => Storage key via KeyVault

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

How do I add below using Terraform

1. Authentication type = "Account Type"
2. Use Keyvault for storage connection key

   ```
    resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_data_lake_storage_gen2" 
    "example" {
      name                  = "example"
      data_factory_id       = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
   -    service_principal_id  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.client_id
        service_principal_key = "exampleKey"
         tenant                = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
         url                   = "https://datalakestoragegen2"
    }
   ```

[image]

Comment: ADLS file system endpoint is not supported when using account key authentication. You can use other authentication types., Please refer this document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory#account-key-authentication

Answer (score 0):

***As per [***microsoft document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory#account-key-authentication)  Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 connector doesn't support account key authentication, You can use other authentication types which i have mentioned below***

- [Service principal authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory#service-principal-authentication)
- [System-assigned managed identity authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory#managed-identity)
- [User-assigned managed identity authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory#user-assigned-managed-identity-authentication)

Comment: Using this documentation I am able to create connector via Azure portal, but I am looking for Terraform code to do the same.       https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal-private